# T-SQL transpose rows to columns based on ID

Tags: sql, pivot, transpose

So I have the following table layout:

[image: table layout]

And I want to "transpose" the data so it looks like this:

[image]

I tried using pivot but due to the complexity of the data I think it's not enough. Now, I don't want you to create the query for me but I do need an advice or a hint on how to tackle this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of artists per song?

Comment: That's exactly the thing. The number of artists per song is a variable.